# Django: How to pass in context variables for registration redux?

Tags: python, django, view, registration

here is the views.py for registration redux. i am a little bit confused and i don't really understand how to pass in context variables.

```
class RegistrationView(BaseRegistrationView):
    SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL = getattr(settings, 'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL', True)
    success_url = 'registration_complete'

    def register(self, request, form):
        if Site._meta.installed:
            site = Site.objects.get_current()
        else:
            site = RequestSite(request)

        if hasattr(form, 'save'):
            new_user_instance = form.save()
        else:
            new_user_instance = UserModel().objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)

        new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(
            new_user=new_user_instance,
            site=site,
            send_email=self.SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL,
            request=request,
        )
        signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                     user=new_user,
                                     request=request)
        return new_user
```

Answer (score 0):

BaseRegistrationView inherits from FormView, which has in its inheritance chain `django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin`. This defines the `get_context_data` method, which returns context as a dict. You can override that method and add in your own variables like so:

```
class RegistrationView(BaseRegistrationView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RegistrationView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['key'] = value 
        return context
```